# Verbs to describe someone's eye movement when they suddenly notice something

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I'm trying to describe a situation arising when two people are having a conversation. Suddenly one of them notices a phrase said by the other, and he keeps it in mind without making any remark about it. In such a situation, he would normally turn his eyes aside and a little bit downward as he registers the phrase and starts thinking about it. I wonder if there are any verbs or phrases that describe such kind of eye movement  in particular, or any other changes in people's behaviour when they suddenly notice something in the dialogue.

P.S. I'm actually writing a screenplay and this is one of my Action lines, so I have to avoid using general description like "the phrase gets A's attention" and find the accurate  verb or phrase. Many thanks.

Comment: Note that "eyesight change" is not an idiomatic way of describing this - in English "eyesight" is associated with the *ability to see*, so an "eyesight change" would always mean an improvement or decline in the person's ability to see.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you for the point. I changed it to "eye movement", though it might still not be accurate.

Comment: (looks doubtful) (looks askance) Generally, the third person is used for a description in a script dialogue.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the advice. But in my story the listener is not suspicious of the speaker or any other thing as he hears the phrase. It's more like the phrase reminds him of something or offers him some new clues, which is shown not through his word but his appearance. But then "looks askance" is a useful phrase and thank you for it.